# Can I prevent a certain PHP post value from being posted?

Tags: php, post

I have multiple variables being posted to a save.php file. I would like to prevent certain variables from being posted so I don't have to add some crazy stuff to my save table in order to not display them (it displays all post variables).

It would be much easier to stop it from posting all together. Is there a away to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have names of the POST variables, you can unset them in the beginning of the script.

Comment: Also, best thing to do is use SSL in this case so it is encrypted between TCP and HTTP layers.

Comment: @user4035

Thanks. No idea why I didn't just do this......thank you!

Comment: @Duniyadnd Aehmmm, can you explain that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of your save.php you'll do this:

```
unset($_POST["key-to-delete"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_intersect_key` with `array_flip` to implement a white-list method:

```
$arr = $_POST;
$allowed = array('name', 'email'); 

array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($allowed)));
```

Will return:

```
Array 
( 
    [name] => Will 
    [email] => will@example.com 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was easier to just unset it at the beginning, though.